# Can the Android API be leveraged to modify the caller's voice during the call?

Tags: java, android, audio, telephony

I can't seem to find any documentation saying this is possible, but Google turned up a few apps that claim to be able to accomplish it.

I'd like to, ideally, be able to play an audio track and have it sent as the caller's voice.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devindia.acr&hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot modify the in-call audio stream, sorry.

Comment: Thought that was the case. Thanks for confirming.