# Android API for call sound stream manipulation

Tags: android

Is there any way to hook voice sound while calling? Can I append this sound stream with for example some music?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the Android API be leveraged to modify the caller's voice during the call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063402/can-the-android-api-be-leveraged-to-modify-the-callers-voice-during-the-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported by Android.

Comment: Can it be implemented on NDK level?

Comment: I seriously doubt it; the carriers would probably be none-too-pleased if this were possible.

See my exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063402/can-the-android-api-be-leveraged-to-modify-the-callers-voice-during-the-call

Comment: As I thought, not possible. See this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3434