# Intercept the outgoing call data, alter it & then write it back out- Why it is not possible?- Android

Tags: android

We are working on an application similar to "Funny Call" on Google Play.

When user makes a call to another another contact, we would be intercepting the call and will add some effects to it and then this modified sound will reach the recipient.

I've searched for the solution to this problem and found out that many developers say Android does not support this. 
[Android API for call sound stream manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204300/android-api-for-call-sound-stream-manipulation)

[Can the Android API be leveraged to modify the caller's voice during the call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063402/can-the-android-api-be-leveraged-to-modify-the-callers-voice-during-the-call#)

But, I would still like to know if its really not possible straight from the horse's mouth. I would like to know if there is any specific reason behind this.

Is there really no way to achieve this?

Can you please also tell me if there is any possibility of this being possible in near future?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there really no way to achieve this?

If you read through the comments on the app you cited, it would appear that they are doing VOIP, and that their servers are then actually placing the call, as that is why there are calling rates to different countries. I see no evidence that they are using the on-device telephony capability. You, of course, are welcome to supply such evidence, if you have any.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yes, I also think, they are not using on-device telephony capability as I could not collect any such evidence. But I was wondering what could be the reason behind not supporting this feature of intercepting call.

Comment: Maybe it's just a massive security hole.